# What is meant by "for all but a finite number of $n$"

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, logic

I'm facing to prove :

If $b≤x_n≤c$ for all but a finite number of n, show that $b≤\liminf{x_n}$.
I couldn't understand what is meant my

"for all but a finite number of n"

Comment: It means that there is a natural number $m$ such that $b\le x_n\le c$ whenever $n\ge m$. There might be some finite number of terms of the sequence that are *not* between $b$ and $c$, but once you get past them, every term is between $b$ and $c$.

Comment: There may be a finite number of exceptions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means that the number of elements of the sequence $\{x_n\}$ out of the closed interval $[a,b]$, is finite ("almost all" of them are in that interval).

Answer (score 0):

Another way to say

> $b \le x_n \le c$ for all but a finite number of $n$.

is

> There is $N \in \mathbb N$ such that $b \le x_n \le c$  for all $n > N$.

Comment: Got it Thanks, I believe it is such a confusing way to express that.

Comment: @Xenidia I think the indirection is deliberate though.  For this level of exercise you probably should use the literal meaning of "all but finitely many", which is that there exists a finite subset $S \subset \mathbb N$ such that $b < x_n < c$ for all $n \in \mathbb N \setminus S$.  You should make sure you can see how to prove the equivalence to this answer (but it's easy).

Comment: This is a bit misleading since it is only indirectly the same as "all but finitely many".  A naive attempt to apply this to interpret "continuous except at finitely many points" would fail, as i'm sure you know :).

Comment: Note, however, that those are equivalent *in this case*. If the base set is not the natural numbers, but e.g. the integers, the two statements are not equivalent, as $a_n<b$ for negative $n$, and $b<a_n<c$ for nonnegative $n$ would fulfil "There is $N\in\mathbb N$ such that $b\le x_n\le c$ for all $n>N$" but not "$b\le x_n\le c$ for all but a finite number of $n$." Replacing $\mathbb N$ by $\mathbb Z$ in the rewritten condition would not help either.